# UDP communication between two directly connected PCs

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, communication

Can I use the UDP protocol to implement the communications between two directly connected PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
The only downfall could be you can't be sure of proper delivery of messages(as in case of TCP).

You'll need to develop a very good application layer code, which would kind of mimic the functionalities of TCP , to achieve a reliable communication.